# Blender no longer opens my blend file, it loads the Export FBX screen and is stuck there

Tags: export

It's completely bizarre, I tried opening the blend file on my other computer, I tried deleting to blend1 file, I tried factory settings, somehow my blend file got corrupted?

Basically I was exporting to FBX, and then it got stuck on that screen, when I exited and reloaded it, it loaded straight to the Export FBX screen, I can't get back to my scene no matter what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file without the *Load UI* option ticked

Go to *File > Open* and browse to open your desired file, but **before you open** uncheck the Load UI option on the bottom left of the File Browser window.

If not, open a new Blender instance and append your scenes from the previous file.

Otherwise post your file here so we can look at it.