# How do I edit a rendered animation?

Tags: rendering, node-editor

I created a short animation and after rendering it, I must have had one/some of the nodes not set correctly.  I want to go back into the file and see what I did wrong, but when I open the file up it defaults to the rendered window.

I have gone through all the window settings and cannot find where/how to re-open the nodes panel to make adjustments and then re-render it.  Sorry if this was answered already.  I searched the forum in various ways and could not find this exact issue.  I consider myself a novice-intermediate level Blender user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender no longer opens my blend file, it loads the Export FBX screen and is stuck there](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65204/blender-no-longer-opens-my-blend-file-it-loads-the-export-fbx-screen-and-is-stu)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-can-i-go-back-to-the-original-interface-layout/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/822/how-do-you-return-to-the-default-view-the-one-you-see-when-blender-starts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're seeing something like this(not including the cube):[image]

then you need to go here:[image]

and change it to node editor (or whatever you need to change it to. there are also other ones like that around.)

Comment: I did that several times, thinking the obvious, and to no avail.  This morning when I saw this, I figured I would do it again in case I was having a brain fart or something.  I was having a brain fart of something it appears.  I'm really at a loss as to why it did not open up.  I just clicked it again and like magic.....all the nodes opened when I clicked the node editor.  Thank you very much!

Comment: oh lol. brain farts can be annoying. np!